# How do you click web page elements without a mouse?

Tags: browsing, pentadactyl, mouseless

I installed Arch Linux a few days ago on my Chromebook C720, but due to some kernel support issues with the touchpad, I'm left with no mouse. I'm not too bothered about fixing it right now though, because I figure it's a good chance to learn how to do things more efficiently - with just the keyboard.

So I've installed [i3](http://i3wm.org/), [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), [Ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/), [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/), and a bunch of other keyboard-based programs, and things are going surprisingly well, except for the lack of ability to click on certain JavaScript buttons, such as the vote buttons on this site. Pentadactyl's hint mode doesn't work because they're not hyperlinks.

Am I missing something, or is this just not possible with Pentadactyl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "vote" buttons on S.O. and friends may not be hyperlinks, but they are anchors. For these links specifically, you can add the following to your `.pentadactylrc`:

```
set hinttags+=a[class^='vote']
```

This setting adds to your list of hinted elements, which will now include `a` elements whose "class" attribute starts with "vote": "vote-up-off", "vote-up-one", etc.

This only works on SO sites, of course, but you should be able to use similar techniques on other sites.